# Align list center while list items are floated left in d-flex

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make inline list which reminds grid that has horizontally as may cards as it can hold. The problem is that If I float list items to left, the text-center no longer works and the list itself is left aligned.

This is the card I am loading into the list item using ajax `.load()`

```
<div class="my-card" style="width: 268px;">
    <a href="" class="card-text">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/268x280" alt="">
        <div class="card-body py-3 px-0">
            <div>Dolor labore duis eu eu qui officia aliqua minim.</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="d-flex text-center">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item float-left"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the same but last items are not floated left but list is centered:

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="d-flex">
                <ul class="list-inline text-center pl-3 justify-content-start">
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So the question is how to center list inside d-flex and float list items to left? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: show your css please(do you use bootstrap?)

Comment: @לבנימלכה I am so sorry, my tags were completly wrong. Yes I am using bootstrap 4. And the only css is inside the card and it is fixed card width.

Comment: Have you tried adding class `justify-content-start` on the container element?

Comment: @jom yes I've tried that also. Result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the entire layout, and keep the last row left aligned, use 4 empty spacer elements at the end of the list. In this case you need exactly 4 spacers since the max you have across a row is 5....

Also, make sure you're using flexbox, and not floats.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="row list-unstyled mx-auto text-center justify-content-center">
        <li class="col-auto">
            <div class="my-card" style="width: 268px;">
                <a href="" class="card-text">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/268x280" alt="">
                    <div class="card-body py-3 px-0">
                        <div>Dolor labore duis eu eu qui officia aliqua minim.</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        ... (more cards)

        <!-- 4 empty spacers at end for left justify cards on all viewports -->
        <li class="col-auto">
            <div class="my-card invisible" style="width: 268px;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-auto">
            <div class="my-card invisible" style="width: 268px;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-auto">
            <div class="my-card invisible" style="width: 268px;"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-auto">
            <div class="my-card invisible" style="width: 268px;"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/jPsNgz6Co8

AFAIK is the only *flexbox* way to center the entire layout, and keep the last row left aligned regardless of number of items and viewport width.