# Bootsrap 5 Getting DIV's (Cols) to Align Start (Stack) on Small Devices and Justify (Inline) on Large Devices within the Navbar?

Tags: layout, navbar, bootstrap-5, justify

I'm trying to upgrade to **Bootstrap 5** as it has some great new features, but I am struggling with the responsive aspects and justifying.

I have a design with **7 columns** that should be evenly spaced on desktop, which works fine.

[image]

However, with switching to mobile the **d-flex** or **justify** seems to override the normal **col** stacking feature.

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is this...

[image]

This is to be an icon style navigation bar and the source code so far is:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar_main" style="width:100%;">

<div class="container">
<div class="row d-lg-flex justify-content-lg-evenly align-items-start">
  
  <div class="col text-center"><span class="fab-icon">Ex</span> <span class="fab-text">Example</span></div>
  <div class="col text-center"><span class="fab-icon">Ex</span> <span class="fab-text">Example</span></div>
  <div class="col text-center"><span class="fab-icon">Ex</span> <span class="fab-text">Example</span></div>
  <div class="col text-center"><span class="fab-icon">Ex</span> <span class="fab-text">Example</span></div>
  <div class="col text-center"><span class="fab-icon">Ex</span> <span class="fab-text">Example</span></div>
  <div class="col text-center"><span class="fab-icon">Ex</span> <span class="fab-text">Example</span></div>
  <div class="col text-center"><span class="fab-icon">Ex</span> <span class="fab-text">Example</span></div>
  
</div>
```

I have tried everything I can think of and been through all the Bootstrap V5 documentation. My guess is, that I am trying to achieve something Bootstrap can't do or I am missing a key item.

If I set to "justify" on all devices, then they don't stack at all. "align-items-start" (and "align-this-start" on each DIV) made no difference.

The only additional non default Bootstrap code used is two CSS styles, which simply style the icon and set text to white.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53701682/align-list-center-while-list-items-are-floated-left-in-d-flex/53706272#53706272

Comment: @zim Thanks, that's got me a step closer I think